# Use if condition error on the query builder in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, query-builder

blade work ok when I send the `keyword` to controller

```
$search_alls = DB::table($table)
                  ->where('title', '=', $keyword)
                  ->where('status','=',0)
                  ->orderBy($wanttime_by, $wanttime_order)
                  ->paginate(9);
```

blade shows error when I do not send the `keyword` to controller

```
$search_alls = DB::table($table);
if ($keyword) {
    $search_alls->where('title', '=', $keyword);
}
$search_alls
    ->where('status','=',0)
    ->orderBy($wanttime_by, $wanttime_order)
    ->paginate(9);
```

the blade view is

```
{{ $search_all->id }}
```

the error message is

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$id

Comment: Could you show all blade view code?

Comment: Also, you should put `$search_alls = $search_alls->where...` within the if and after the if so that it updates the variable.

Comment: what do you get when you do `dd($search_all)` in your view if you don't pass the `$keyword` ?

Comment: Are you using a foreach in the blade? because you have search_alls and search_all ...... what is the content of search_alls when you do not send the keyword? check that

Comment: @thisiskelvin  I fix the question thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_alls = DB::table($table);
        if ($keyword) {
            $search_alls=$search_alls->where('title', '=', $keyword);
        }

        $search_alls=$search_alls
        ->where('status','=',0)
        ->orderBy($wanttime_by, $wanttime_order)
        ->paginate(9);
```

thanks @thisiskelvin ! And everybody's help!